# Calling REST API from controller codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, rest, codeigniter, api

I am new to code igniter and for my project I have to create a REST API.

I have a working REST API.

What is the correct way to call the API from ajax calls?

```
View -> Controller -> REST
```

or

```
View ->REST
```

If it is `View -> Controller -> REST`, how to call REST API from controller?

This is my class which extends the rest_controller for users

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class User extends REST_Controller {

    function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('usermodel');

    }

    public function user_get(){
        $this->load->model('usermodel');
        $requestType = $this->get('req');//get method request
        switch ($requestType) {
            case 'login':
                $username = $this->get('un');
                $password = $this->get('pw');
                $user =  $this->usermodel->getUser($username, $password);
                if ($user){
                    $this->response($user, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
                }else{
                    $this->response([
                        'status' => FALSE,
                        'message' => 'No users were found'
                    ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); 
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ajex call from my login page for login user

```
    function signIn(){
    var username = $('#signInUn').val();
    var password = $('#signInPw').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url : "/infoshare/index.php/user/user/req/login/un/"+username+"/pw/"+password,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data){
            var response = data.response;
            var status = data.status;
            if(status == 200){
                var userId = response[0].user_id;
                //success of user 
            }else{
                console.log(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(status){
            console.log("Error occured");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can use `curl` or `file_get_contents`

Comment: thank you for the quick response. the problem is that, this project is for my assignment and curl and file_get_contents are not yet covered. if there is another approach please do tell

Comment: did you place API files in your project according to API documentation?

Comment: Are you saying you need your own Rest API? Question is not very clear. If you have a controller for your rest should be able to call that controller using ajax without needing to use a view

Comment: @HikmatSijapati  Yes I added the relevant files in the correct paths.

Comment: @charlietfl The problem i am having is that i have an ajex call inside the view to a REST api. That works but i need to create a session in php if the ajex response is success. In order to do that i need access the controller right ? So because of that Do i need to call the controller function from ajex or the REST API ?

Comment: then in your controller extends the `REST_Controller` and call the controller's function from ajax.

Comment: This is still confusing. Is the REST Api yours ? Or is the ajax call made to third party api? Please show relevant code

Comment: @HikmatSijapati I have a controller and another class which extends the REST_Controller . 

I would be needing to call the class which extends the REST controller from a controller. 

The reason for this is that I have a logging page and once a user is logged ( this uses ajex ) and from the ajex I call the REST API but i need to create a session once the ajex gives a success response. So the session should be created from the controller if i am not mistaken right ? That is the reason i need to call the REST from my controller

Comment: @charlietfl : Yes the REST API is mine. and its located in my localhost

Comment: So it's not clear why you can't set session when ajax call is made to it then

Comment: @charlietfl the ajex url is set directly to the REST API and not the controller. 

Can i create the session from REST Class ?

Comment: Code is added to the question

Comment: Yes...sure you can. It's all php regardless of it's use case. As for it being codeigniter you can load any libraries, helpers, models etc also in the rest class also

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you so much.. :) :)

Comment: Think of it this way, the REST_Controller class is simply a specialized controller

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for that explanation. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can call rest apil through ajax.

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "GET",
data: {id:1123},
url: "http://localhost:8080/restws/json/user/get",
success: function(data){        
 alert(data);

  }
   });
```

Pass the data which you need for the method. Also check you request type if POST or GET.

Comment: no such thing as post with jsonp...not supported. If you are setting jsonp you better explain how to generate the output and why you are even using it